# Cheapest way to mirror an ASP web application on IIS with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2005-express, mirroring, web-farm

Rather than relying on one server, is it possible to achieve high availability with two servers and no hardware load balancer?

Either Network Load Balancing and have SQL Server Express mirrored between the two servers (IIS would be on both servers too) or using something like Round Robin DNS and again mirrored databases between two servers?

Comment: @Tom: Classic ASP, or ASP.NET? Also, I didn't know SQL Server Express supported mirorring. Are you sure?

Comment: Classic ASP :( and yes, SQL Express doesnt support it. Moved over to ServerFault with a new question: http://serverfault.com/questions/129557/high-availability-with-2-servers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use IIS 7, you can just install ARR (Application Request Routing http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting ).
To sync the content you can use Web Deploy to sync the content ( http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy ).

Syncing SQL Express is something that I would not be able to help, I would strongly recommend using a full SQL Server and just point both servers to it.